# Setting the height of two controls to be the same

Tags: c#, winforms

How can I make two controls share the same height. I have set the Size to be the same for both controls but when I run it, I am seeing a difference.

```
 this.txtUserName.Size = new System.Drawing.Size(382, 45);
   this.btnLogin.Size = new System.Drawing.Size(75, 45);
```

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Actually both **have** the same `Height` as you set them. However in order to accomodate various `BorderStyles` (or `FlatStyles` as it is called in the case of `Buttons`) the full size is not always **visible**.

So, the `Button` will **look** to be **one** pixel smaller on each side than the `Height` is has with these (current) appearances:

```
button1.FlatStyle = FlatStyle.Standard
button1.FlatStyle = FlatStyle.System
```

The full Size will be visible with

```
button1.FlatStyle = FlatStyle.Popup
button1.FlatStyle = FlatStyle.Flat
```

If you are sure about your choice of `FlatStyle` you may want to adapt their Height (and Location!)  accordingly..

To further complicate thing the `TextBox`'s visible Height will change if you set its BorderStyle from `FixedSingle` or `Fixed3D` to `None`: It will shrink by **7** (!) pixels..

Note that as far as I remember, all those details of the borderstyles depend on the Windows version & Visual Styles on the target machine.. I am running W8.1 here

Answer (score 0):

Open the Form.Designer.cs and go to InitializeComponent() method for the form, you'll see initialization code for all components on the form.

If you are setting these values prior to InitializeComponent() call from the constructor, it'll be lost. Otherwise you may need to check Margin and Padding of the components.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/ms229627(v=vs.100).aspx